# HttpWebResponse hangs/freezes when running in a WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using a C# WebAPI project which would call an external API based on its URL. However, when I am trying to retrieve the data back, it hangs/freezes.

The code where it stops is:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);
```

I don't understand why it is stopping though. Could it be interfering with the API request I am also making? When I run this code as part of a unit test, I would get a response back within seconds. I don't think it is the API service itself, I think it is my code. I have already tried various API URLS. None of them work.

My full code is:

```
public static async Task<string> CallWebAPi<T>(string url)
{
    string returnValue;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    returnValue = await strReader.ReadToEndAsync();

    return returnValue;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are supposed to process the response in `EndGetResponse`. I don't think `FromAsync` is meant to be `await`ed. I think you are deadlocking and if you want to go async then use `HttpClient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible deadlock [ConfigureAwait(false)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx),  here are a good explanation from Stephen on what cause [deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

```
  var response = (HttpWebResponse)await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Adding `.ConfigureAwait(false);` has got my code working! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use the synchronous functions, create a Task and await this task:

```
var response = await Task.Run(() => 
{
    return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
});
```

Comment: Doing that is rolling the dice because the Asp.Net runtime doesn't know about that thread and it will die if the application decides to recycle.

Comment: @Crowcoder If there is a running request the runtime will not fire a recycle. If there's the possibility of this to happen (the current request finish before the http request is finished) then using `Page.RegisterAsyncTask` will avoid that problem.

Comment: Just tried your answer and it unfortunately doesn't work. Thank you for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

- you dont need Task.Factory.FromAsync. HttpWebRequest already supports asynchronous operations.
- You have defined a generic method `CalWebApi<T>` but have never used a generic type

if your operation is async, use this.

```
    public async Task<T> CalWebApiAsync<T>(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";
        using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    var stringResult = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    T objectResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(stringResult);
                    return objectResult;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`var result = await CallWebApiAsync<YourType>("exteranlapiurl");`

if your operation is not async, use this..

```
     public T CalWebApi<T>(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    var stringResult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    T objectResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(stringResult);
                    return objectResult;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`var result = CallWebApi<YourType>("exteranlapiurl");`

Comment: Just tried using your code, I'm getting the same result. Works fine during unit tests, but won't seem to work when it is being used in the API. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unsure what you mean?

Comment: I would call CallWebApi() by saying `jsonResult = CallWebAPi<string>(APIUrl).Result;` This will (or should) return a Json string.

Comment: where in async method or sync method ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do my Request. Each Part is in an own Function. Its create the Request and you can get the Response synchronous.

```js
public HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string Url, string Method, string ContentType, object Content, List<RequestHeader> headers)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);

    request.Method = Method;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContentType)) request.ContentType = ContentType;
    else if(Content != null) request.ContentType = "application/json";

    if (Content != null)
    {
        var postData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Content);
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }

    foreach(RequestHeader header in Headers)
    {
        request.Headers.Add(header.Type, header.Value);
    } //class at the end.

    return request;
}
        
public string GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    var retval = "";
    try
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        retval = ReadResponse(response);
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        resolveException(ex.Message);
    }
    return retval;
}

public string ReadResponse(HttpWebResponse response)
{
    var retval = "";
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            retval = responseText;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        resolveException(ex.Message);
    }

    return retval;
}

public class RequestHeader
{
    public HttpRequestHeader Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```